# Make invisible body line box2d libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I want to make these body lines invisible, because it's a lot that was left in the games, and that body circle too. The squares are of a layer tiled map.
The circle is a body of a sprite.

[Circle and Squares in game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6q4i.png)

Comment: you're drawing that lines, either by `box2ddebugrenderer` or `stage debug renderer`. stop drawing, make body line invisible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable or disable debug drawing different parts of your box2d world. You can set this flags in [constructor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Box2DDebugRenderer.html#Box2DDebugRenderer-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-):

```
// create renderer with default values
Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer = Box2DDebugRenderer(
                      /*drawBodies*/         true,
                      /*drawJoints*/         true,
                      /*drawAABBs*/          false,
                      /*drawInactiveBodies*/ true,
                      /*drawVelocities*/     false,
                      /*drawContacts*/       true)
```

or set only one flag (for example *drawBodies*):

```
debugRenderer.setDrawBodies(false);
```

Look also [full API reference](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Box2DDebugRenderer.html)